# Android: How to get intent filter's `path` value in an action

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have a `<intent-filter>` with `schema` and `host` matching and is working fine. Now for the same intent URI I've added path value and no `path` attribute added for `<intent-filter>`'s  tag.
Still my activity is getting called correctly, but I need to access the `path` value passed.

How can I?

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: what code have you got so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Uri` included in the `Intent` that was used to start your activity by calling `getData()` on the `Intent`, which you get by calling `getIntent()` on your `Activity`.